# Deploy update on Meteor by unpacking

Tags: meteor, deployment, zip, bundle, gzip

I have an already live website which is built on Meteor. In the root folder, I see bundle.tar.gz and bundle.zip

Meteor developer is on leave and I am a PHP Developer, I need to make modifications to the styles so I have unzipped both folders on my local and made the changes.

Could someone please help to deploy these to the server? Can we not deploy in an unpackaged form?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have patched the bundles, which isn't a great idea as all of the stylesheets are concatenated together and minified. Being as it it, I'll let that go.

Deploying them will depend very much on the environment, and what other services are deployed, and therefore how to do an upgrade.

You should have a look at the Meteor Deployment guide:
https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html

If you are running on Galaxy it is easier, if you are running Nginx and Phusion Passenger it's not too bad either. Other combinations are possible, with varying degrees of difficulty.